# python-oracledb thin client returns DPY-6005

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

I'm trying to connect to a 21c ATP and 19c ADP (free tier, ACL enabled/configured with "My Address", TLS enabled (mTLS set to "Not required"), connection string contains "ssl_server_dn_match=yes") using Python's **thin client** but at the point of making a connection or setting up a connection pool, I get:

> ```
> OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection
> failed with  "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
> failed: self signed certificate  in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)"
> ```

**Envioronment**:

DB: ATP 21c and ADP 19c

Python client library: oracledb-1.2.1 (I've tried 1.2.0 and 1.1.1, as well, but to no avail)

Environment: Python 3.10.4 and 3.8.10 (running on Mac OS)

**Code sample:**

```
import oracledb

# copied from the ATP's "Database Connection"
cs='''(description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1521)(host=adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloud.com))(connect_data=(service_name=xxxx.adb.oraclecloud.com))(security=(ssl_server_dn_match=yes)))'''

connection = oracledb.connect(user="admin", password="<password>", dsn=cs)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    try:
        sql = """select systimestamp from dual"""
        for r in cursor.execute(sql):
            print(r)

    except oracledb.Error as e:
        error, = e.args
        print(error.message)
        print(sql)
        if (error.offset):
            print('^'.rjust(error.offset+1, ' '))
```

**References:**

I've used the following documents as a reference:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/easy-way-to-connect-python-applications-to-oracle-autonomous-databases
- https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/writing-a-flask-application-using-python-oracledb
- https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connecting-python-tls.html#GUID-CA446B91-BC48-4A66-BF69-B8D54B9CBAD4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error tells you that the certificate supplied by the server is not one that any local certificate authority recognizes (which is necessarily the case with self-signed certificates). Two options are available to resolve this:

1. Tell the OS the certificate is acceptable by adding it to the OS certificate "store"
2. Use an Oracle wallet (ewallet.pem) that contains the relevant certificates and set the `wallet_location` parameter appropriately. This was discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/issues/65).

Comment: If I use the second approach, would I be effectively using the thick client? Regarding the first approach: maybe I'm overlooking something but I can't find anything in the documentation about that. I've used 4 different documents as a reference (all produced by Oracle employees) but none of them say anything about the 1st approach. Am I missing something in the docs?

Comment: No, if you use the second approach you are not using the thick client as can be seen in the issue I referenced. As for the documentation, the assumption has always been that for public facing cloud databases that self-signed certificates are not used. I'm not sure if this is a server configurtion issue or a client configuration issue. For most people it "just works"!

Comment: Babak, FWIW I just tried your code against my database and it worked without issues. Python 3.9.13 with the Oracle driver 1.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, Yasin. Yeah, there's nothing in the code. I'm not sure what's causing the issue. Obviously using the .pem file from the wallet worked. I was hoping that I could simply use the EZconnect method and avoid having to rely on wallet (because then I have to automate installing the cli binary and setting it up and downloading the wallet, etc) ...

Comment: It may be a client issue as well. If yours is not a sensitive database, can I try connecting to it if you could open it up to the internet and send me the connect info? If it is possible you can Twitter DM or email me the details.

Comment: Absolutely. It's not a sensitive DB yet :) I've started it today and I was testing connectivity. I don't have your email but my email is babak.tourani@itech.media

Comment: `pip install certifi` ?

Comment: @ChristopherJones, No, that didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Update: The issue seems to be related to my Mac. I just tried it on an OL8 node and everything’s fine… well, in a way:

Using the complete connection string works fine (and that solves my problem) but if I want to use the “host” and “service_name” parameters of the “oracledb.connect” method, it will reply with a “DPY-4011”. 

I would also get a DPY-4011, if I use the EZconnect connections string for the “dsn” parameter like “adb.uk-london-1.oraclecloud.com/xxx.adb.oraclecloud.com”.

Comment: You need to also use the `protocol` parameter; otherwise, you are using TCP instead of TCPS!

Comment: Thanks, @AnthonyTuininga. I was just testing different combination of parameters (thanks to help from Yasin) and I noticed that the protocol is a required parameter here. I'm writing a blog post on it as a future reference for myself.

Comment: I have an older blog post showing how to map the wallet tnsnames.ora connect strings to Easy Connect Syntax: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/how-to-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks, That's interesting. I got the EZconnect working by adding the protocol like a URL parameter "<host>:port/<service>?protocol=tcps"

I'll try the "tcps://<host>:port/<service>" as well!